# How do I know which function will be called?

Tags: c++, class, ambiguity

Today I found the following disturbingly ambiguous situation in our code base:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void Irrelevant_Function(void) = 0;

protected:
    C_Container *   Get_Container(void);
};

class A : public Base, public Not_Important {
public:
    inline C_Container *    Get_Container(void);
};

class B : public Base, protected SomethingElse {
public:
    C_Container *   Get_Container(void);
};
```

Many things were calling the Get_Container method, but not always calling the correct one - note that none of these functions were virtual.

I need to rename the methods `Get_Base_Container`, `Get_A_Container`, etc to remove the ambiguity. What rules does C++ use to determine which version of a function it should call? I'd like to start from the "known state" of what should have been getting called, and then figure out the bugs from there.

For example, if I have a pointer to a Base and call Get_Container, I assume it would just call the Base version of the function. What if I have a pointer to an A? What about a pointer to a B? What about an A or B on the heap?

Thanks.

Comment: If you've got the `=0;` in the base class the way you've written it, it won't compile.  The `=0` can only be used with pure virtual methods.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the virtual there (and the return type, oops).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends how you're calling the function.  If you're calling through an `A *`, an `A &` or an `A`, then you'll be calling `A::Get_Container()`.  If you're calling through a `Base *`, a `Base &` (even if they point to/reference an `A`), then you'll be calling `Base::Get_Container()`.

Answer (score 3):

As long as there's no virtual inheritance going on, it's quite easy. If you're working directly with an object, it's the object's method that gets called; if you're working with a pointer or reference, it's the type of the pointer or reference that determines the method, and the type of the object pointed to doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

A method is first looked up according to the object's *static type.*  If it is non-virtual there, you're done: that's the method that's called.  The dynamic type is what virtual methods, dynamic_cast, and typeid use, and is the "actual" type of the object.  The static type is what the static type system works with.

```
A a;                       // Static type and dynamic type are identical.
Base &a_base = a;          // Static type is Base; dynamic type is A.

a.Get_Contaienr();         // Calls A::Get_Container.
a_base.Get_Container();    // Calls Base::Get_Container.

B *pb = new B();           // Static type and dynamic type of *pb (the pointed-to
                           // object) are identical.
Base *pb_base = pb;        // Static type is Base; dynamic type is B.

pb->Get_Container();       // Calls B::Get_Container.
pb_base->Get_Container();  // Calls Base::Get_Container.
```

I've assumed above that the protected Base::Get_Container method is accessible, otherwise those will be compile errors.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of additional points to note here:

Name lookup occurs in a single scope; E.g. When calling the  method on an object with static type 'B', the compiler considers the interface of 'B' to determine whether or not there is a valid match. If there is not, it only then looks at the interface of Base to find a match. This is why that from the compiler's view, there is no ambiguity and it can resolve the call. If your real code has overloading etc. this may be an issue.

Secondly, it is often forgotten that the 'protected' keyword applies at class and not object level. So for example:

```
class Base {
protected:
    C_Container *   Get_Container(void);
};

class B : public Base{
public:
    C_Container *   Get_Container(void)
    {
        B b;
        // Call the 'protected' base class method on another object.
        return b.Base::Get_Container();
    }
};
```